Construct a non-noetherian ring with finite krull dimension
As learning Krull dimension in commutative algebra recently, I cannot successfully construct a non noetherian ring of finite krull dimension. I think the ring must have some special conditions like having some prime ideals with infinite generators. Could somebody help me？
